# why is the diameter different on these two Bezier curves using the same Bezier circle as a bevel object?

Tags: bevel, bezier-curves

I have created three closed Bezier curves. The first, "loop" and the second "shape" are simple Bezier circle that have been scaled and the scale applied. The third, "knot", started out as a Bezier circle.  In edit mode, I added 3 more Bezier circles, positioned them, and then edited them to be connected into a single curve.

Next, I set the Bevel object on loop and knot to shape.  I expected two closed tubes of the same diameter, but instead the diameters are different.  Why are the diameters different?

I know I can duplicate shape, rescale the duplicate and use it as the Bevel object for one of the paths, but I would like to understand what is going on.[image: render of the blend file]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter edit mode and select the vertices of the curves you can see it in the n panel that the radius of the vetices of the thicker one is set to 2.5 while the other one has vertices with radius of 1.
[image]

If the profile needs to be a simple circle you do not need to use another curve as Bevel shape at all. You could also just set the fill type to Full in the curve properties and then set a desired Bevel Depth. You will need to increase the resolution for it to be round as well:

[image]

It might be a few clicks less to set it up this way.

Comment: That is indeed what I missed.  I'm using a Bezier curve as the bevel shape because the final version will be a fairly complex shape, but, of course, your approach would work for a tube shape.