# Why are these curves different sizes when they are using the same bevel object?

Tags: bevel, bezier-curves

Bezier curves 1, 2 and 3 are all using the curve "Bev ob" as a bevel object. Why are they different sizes?

[image]

I saw [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/115809/61150) and checked that the radius is set the same for all vertices on all three objects.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91782/distorted-mesh-when-i-use-a-bevel-object-on-nurbs-curve-vs-bezier-curve/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70394/why-curve-bevel-not-in-shape/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks. That one answered my question. It was a matter of scaling off on one and radius on another.